# How to display without [' '] in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, lxml

I'm scraping a webpage using lxml in python

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page=requests.get(url)
tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
name=tree.xpath(xpath)
print name
```

It's displaying: `['Matthew']`

I want to display: `Matthew`

Any solutions?

Comment: You know that those characters have syntactic meaning? The square brackets indicate a list, the quotes a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing `['Matthew']` because it is a list which contains a single element, the string `'Matthew'`.

You can remove it from the list by simple indexing it.

```
name = tree.xpath(xpath)[0]
```

which will remove the first element.

Note that if the list is empty, this will return an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one element in the list, as you had mentioned ['Matthew'], then use list index of 0. if there are more elements, change the index accordingly. But incase of an error, like no item present,it'll raise an error.

ie in your case, try using, `print name[0]`